# cometd javascript client can receive the broadcast message when client subscribe and server restart

Tags: javascript, spring, cometd

Detail Explanation of the post on further analysis
[Cometd javascript client doesn't subscribe to broadcast channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636294/cometd-javascript-client-doesnt-subscribe-to-broadcast-channel).

If the Cometd-Spring  program start broadcasting the new message and the  cometd javascript client subscribe later, the client is not able to receive the **new broadcast message**. However, the client start receiving the broadcast message after the cometd server restart.

Broadcast Channel: **/notification**

Client Code:

```
  function _metaHandshake(handshake)
     {
         if (handshake.successful === true)     
         {
        cometd.batch(function(){        
        cometd.subscribe('/notification', function(message){
                            console.log("Received Data ::"+JSON.stringify(message.data));
                           });
             });

         }

     }
```

Server Code:

```
@javax.inject.Named 
@javax.inject.Singleton 
@Service("notificationService")
public class NotificationService {


    @Inject
    private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;

    @Session
    private LocalSession session;


    @Configure("/notification")
            public void configureServiceChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel)
            {
                channel.setPersistent(true);// channel persistent
                channel.addAuthorizer(GrantAuthorizer.GRANT_ALL);   
            }


        public void onExternalEvent( Map<String, Object> data)
        {

         this.bayeuxServer.getChannel("/notification").publish(this.session, data);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you send a single message before the client is subscribed.
If that is the case, then of course the client will not receive the message at that point.

If the client subscribes after the message has been sent, then it is wrong to expect that the client will be able to receive the message. The message is now gone.

CometD does not store messages because this is an application-specific behavior.

If your client wants to receive a message that has been sent when it was not subscribed, your application has to do something application-specific to store messages that you want to be delivered later.

Comment: For more clarification - client doesn't receive the new broadcast message after subscription...

Comment: Enable debug logging and double check you are not instantiating 2 instances of BayeuxServer. See http://docs.cometd.org/reference/troubleshooting.html. The Spring documentation is at http://docs.cometd.org/reference/java_server.html#java_server_services_integration_spring. Server and client debug logs are your best tool. You can report them in the CometD mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cometd-users) for more detailed analysis.